# set background of html table's tr

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'd like to set the background of a table row.
The background can be an image or CSS (preferably).
I want it to look something like this, with opacity of the background:

[image]

I've tried it using a repeating image. Here is the image I'm using.

[image]

but it looks like this for some reason:

[image]

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="chPurchaseTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>u/m</th>
            <th>Price Each</th>
            <th>Line Total</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>       
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

and my CSS

```
#chPurchaseTable thead tr{
    background:url('../images/rarrows.png') repeat; 
}
```

How can I achieve this affect?

Comment: Looks like the image dimension is larger than the table row. The triangles are actually the top-most part of your arrows as pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to make use of:**

```
background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT3CO.png') repeat;
  background-size: contain; /*To make sure the entire image fits the container */
```

```css
#chPurchaseTable thead tr {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT3CO.png') repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="chPurchaseTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>u/m</th>
      <th>Price Each</th>
      <th>Line Total</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

To make the background transparent like you require, ***apply the background on a psuedoelement with opacity*** instead of on the actual tr:

```css
#chPurchaseTable thead tr {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#chPurchaseTable thead tr::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT3CO.png') repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table id="chPurchaseTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>u/m</th>
      <th>Price Each</th>
      <th>Line Total</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```